# How to create a grid with up and down in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a grid with 3 columns, each column have 4 rows. First and last one start with margin-top 0, center one start with margin-top of 15px [image]

Above image is for example.
Thanks for the help.

I added the image, I want a code for this example in css

```
.hand-item-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--player-count), auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, auto);
  column-gap: calc(var(--card-gap) * 2);
}
.hand-grid-columns {
  padding: var(--card-gap);
  display: grid;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-gap: var(--card-gap);
}
```

```
       
   <div
      className="hand-grid-columns"
      id={`hand-grid-col-${i + 1}`}
      key={i}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
    >
      {hand.map((card,j) => {
        
          <HandGridData
            key={`${card.rank}${card.suit}`}
            card={card}
            player={i}
            trump={props.trump}
            share={props.share}
            forLayer={props.forLayer}
          />
        
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @RubenSmn I added the code, but i don't know it will help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flex layout. flexDirection style attribute would control the direction of elements within the div.

```js
const App = ()=> {
  const noOfColumns = 3;
  const noOfRows = 4;
  const Box = () => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "white",
          marginTop: 2,
          border: "6px solid",
          width: 50,
          height: 50
        }}
      ></div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", backgroundColor: "darkgray" }}>
      {[...Array(noOfColumns)].map((e, i) => (
        <div
        key={i}
          style={{
            marginRight: 10,
            marginTop: (i + 1) % 2 == 0 ? 15 : 0
          }}
        >
          {[...Array(noOfRows)].map((e, i) => (
            <Box 
        key={i}/>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```